# Whether the APIs in kernel32.dll (or others) have subrutines

Tags: windows, api, hook

I was wondering that whether the APIs in kernel32.dll (or others) have subrutines.
For example the CopyFile function, it should take different action to copy file from C: to D: and from a netshare path (\HOSTNAME\SHAREDFOLDER\FILENAME) to somewhere, or trigger the windows server 2012 (hyper-v) new feature [ODX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
So in the definition of the CopyFile function, there should be some if/else branch, and call some sub function, isn't it?
If the subrutines exist. Is it possible to call the these sub functions directly, and is it possible to hook them?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you're having where you think that hooking these functions is the solution?

Comment: The situation is that I need to implement my software to support Windows Server 2012 new feature ODX. Reference to MSDN it's said that to use CopyFile API and then the system could handle the rest. However if a system environment dosen't meet the ODX requirement, the CopyFile call won't failed, just get a normal performance. So it's hard to convince my users that it's because their environment dosen't meet the requirement, not the bug of the software.

Comment: That's not the same as patching CopyFile. You want to know whether a call to `CopyFile` will proceed with ODX. You can issue the IOCTLs yourself to verify that the source and destination support ODX.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the current implementation of `kernel32.dll` calls functions in `ntdll.dll`. The functions in `ntdll.dll` then do a syscall into the kernel somehow.

To answer your question, yes, it calls subroutines, and they probably can be hooked, but most of the logic about how specifically to read from and write to filesystems in different ways is probably buried in the kernel.

Keep in mind that you're probably not supposed to be digging into the internals of these DLLs — it's best to use the public interface. Relying on implementation details makes your code more fragile and likely to break with operating system upgrades.